# Questions about \fbox

Tags: boxes, framed

I would like to put a text and a math formula inside a `\fbox`, but I got an error:`ERROR: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` Also the`\\` did not work, so the text and the formula are still in one line.

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\fbox{%
  text\\
  $\begin{cases}
    abcdefghijklmn\\
    cdefg
   \end{cases}$
\caption{a_caption}
\label{a_label}
\end{figure}
```

Another question is that it seems that the width of the frame is up to the width of what I put inside `fbox`, what to do if I want the width to be the width of the page?

Could anyone help? Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't seem to have closed your `\fbox`!

Comment: Few issues: You are using inline math with the `$$` and yet trying to insert a newline ``\\``. Also the underscores will need to be escaped as in `a\_caption`.

Comment: Only in the caption, in the label it doesn't hurt.

Comment: @Herbert: I get `Missing $ inserted.` if I don't escape the underscores.

Comment: yes, for the caption, but not for the label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Regarding `\fbox`, as Joseph said: there's a closing brace missing, determining the end of the argument.
- For the whole text width you could use the [`framed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/framed) package and its environment with the same name, such as

  ```
  \usepackage{framed}
  ...
  \begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{framed}
    \centering
    text\\
    $\begin{cases}
      abcdefghijklmn\\
      cdefg
     \end{cases}$
  \end{framed}
  \caption{a caption}
  \label{a_label}
  \end{figure}
  ```
- Another option is the improved version [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed).
- For framing math environments, there's the `\boxed` command of `amsmath`.

Answer (score 4):

you have to use a parbox if you want a linebreak inside fbox. E.g. with package `varwidth`:

```
\fbox{\varwidth{\linewidth}%       
text\\       
$\begin{cases}         
   abcdefghijklmn\\         
   cdefg        
 \end{cases}$\endvarwidth}
```

[image]