# Centering a \framebox

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes

Before asking, I have checked [Centered box, text inside it flushed right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53168/34618), [Questions about \fbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25490/34618), and [Any way to center text within a \parbox?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55860/any-way-to-center-text-within-a-parbox/55861#55861).

Here I have tested various centering methods (my intention is to use `\centering` only) on `\framebox` and `\makebox` alike.

```
\framebox{This is a sentence of text.}\par
\makebox{This is a sentence of text.}\par

{\indent \centering\framebox{This is a sentence of text.}}\par
{\indent \centering\makebox{This is a sentence of text.}}\par

\framebox{\centering This is a sentence of text.}\par
\makebox{\centering This is a sentence of text.}\par

\framebox[5cm]{\centering This is a sentence of text.}\par
\makebox[5cm]{\centering This is a sentence of text.}\par

\framebox[\linewidth]{This is a sentence of text.}\par
\makebox[\linewidth]{This is a sentence of text.}\par

\framebox[5cm]{\centering This is a sentence of text.}\par
\makebox[5cm]{\centering This is a sentence of text.}\par

\framebox{\centering\parbox{5cm}{This is a sentence of text.}}\par
\makebox{\centering\parbox{5cm}{This is a sentence of text.}}\par

\parbox{5cm}{\centering\framebox{This is a sentence of text.}}\par
\parbox{5cm}{\centering\makebox{This is a sentence of text.}}\par

\begin{center}
\framebox{This is a sentence of text.}\par
\makebox{This is a sentence of text.}
\end{center}
```

The only standard LaTeX method (no packages) I can achieve is using the center environment (the last one). Is that so, and why?

An image is shown below. [image]

Comment: Insert the `\par` *inside* the group, not outside and you'll see something different. For example `{...\centering...\par}`.

Comment: @Werner Only the second set works, having the effect. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It isn't clear whether you want to centre text *within* a framebox (what you said) or to centre a framebox within the page (what the last example does).

`\framebox` (line `\makebox`, `\mbox` etc) makes a horizontal box (LR box in the terminology of the latex book) as such it makes a singe line, so paragraph settings like `\centering` have no effect. The text is centred by default (like a tabular `c` column) which you can see if you use the optional width argument and specify a width wider than the text.

```
\noindent
\framebox[\linewidth]{This is a sentence of text.}
```

If you want paragraph material withn the box you need to nest a parbox such as

```
\fbox{\parbox{8cm}{\centering .....}}
```

To center a box in the text area you can use

```
\begin{center}\fbox{...}\end{center}
```

or

```
{\centering\fbox{...}\par}
```

where the first also adds some vertical space. Note that paragraph settings like `\centering` take effect at the *end* of the paragraph, so you need to close the group after the paragraph has finished.

Comment: My intention is the latter, framebox within the page.

Comment: @Jesse yes sorry I'd misread some of your examples (as you may have noticed in a comment I deleted on your question) Hopefully the last bit of the answer does what you want and the first part explains why the other examples didn't work

Comment: Would it be correct to say that \centering is for vertical box?

Comment: @Jesse "vertical mode" is the tex terminology or "par mode" the latex one, but basically yes that is correct.